# Pushing content to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I'm trying to add content from a div to an array. Basically if you click the divs for Apple, Banana and Kiwi, the resulting array will store 'Apple, Banana, Kiwi' in the order they were clicked.

```
$('.fruit').click(function addFruit() {
  var fruits = [];
  var fruit = $(this).text();
  fruits.push(fruit);
  $('.result').text(fruits + ', ');
});
```

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bjhj5p41/2/

Any ideas?

Comment: Make `var fruits = [];` global..Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/bjhj5p41/3/

Comment: The local variable `fruits` is re-initialized on each call, so it will always lose the single value that was pushed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var fruits = [];  // make it global
$('.fruit').click(function() { // no need to use addFruit here
  var fruit = $(this).text();
  fruits.push(fruit);
  $('.result').text(fruits); // use (fruits) cause its an array it will return commas itself
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/bjhj5p41/5/)

**ِAdditional:** I think no need to push the same value twice in array so you can use

```
if($.inArray(fruit,fruits) == -1){
   // value not in array
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/bjhj5p41/6/)